# Size in bytes of the content of a slice

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to send some data to OpenGl.  Sending an array is easy thanks to Sizeof:

```
array := [...]Whatever {lots of data}
array_ptr := gl.Pointer(&array[0])
array_size := gl.Sizeiptr(unsafe.Sizeof(array))
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array_size, array_ptr, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

I would like to use slices instead of arrays because the size of my 3D models is not known at compile time.

**How do I retrieve the size, *in bytes*, of the content of a slice?**  I thought of this:

```
size := uintptr(len(slice)) * unsafe.Sizeof(slice[0])
```

but it is not very general.  Indeed, I need to know the underlying type of the slice in order for this to work, and this supposes that all the elements of the array have the same size.

I could also loop over the whole slice and add all the sizes of every element.  It's not very fast.

I am ready to always keep the len(s)==cap(s), can that help me?

**Edit: implementation of the proposed solution using runtime reflection**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func ElemSize(container interface{}) uintptr {
    return reflect.TypeOf(container).Elem().Size()
}
func ElemSizeVerbose(container interface{}) uintptr {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(container)
    e := t.Elem()
    s := e.Size()
    fmt.Println(t, e, s)
    return s
}
func main() {
    a := [...]int8{2, 3, 5, 7, 11} // Array
    s := []int64{2, 3, 5, 7, 11} // Slice
    z := []int32{} // Even empty things
    ElemSizeVerbose(a) // [5]int8 int8 1
    ElemSizeVerbose(s) // []int64 int64 8
    ElemSizeVerbose(z) // []int32 int32 4
}
```

Comment: Give an example of a slice or array where all the elements do not have the same size? An array of any struct will have all elements the same size, as will an array of pointers or interface{}.

Comment: Good point.  I had arrays of strings in mind, or arrays of arrays.  But they the topmost array just contains a pointer I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a slice or array, every element is always the same size. Therefore, your example will work as long as len(s) > 0. In other words, as long as the slice has at least one element in it. Otherwise it will panic.

To avoid the need of having an element in the slice, I recommend using the following:

```
 uintptr(len(s)) * reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem().Size()
```

Comment: @jnml any way to avoid that?

Comment: a) manually: eg. size of `struct{foo, bar int}` can be easily written as a compile time constant. b) hardcoding it and verifying the value in some_test.go c) preprocessing d) unsafe.Sizeof is a compile time [constant](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants): "A constant value is represented by a rune, integer, floating-point, imaginary, or string literal, an identifier denoting a constant, a constant expression, a conversion with a result that is a constant, or the result value of some built-in functions such as unsafe.Sizeof applied to any value, ... ". e) ...? (In no specific order)

Comment: I'm accepting Stephen's answer because it also addresses my wish of calculating the size of []interface{}.

Comment: Beware that passing `[]interface{}` to the C world probably makes no sense. (At least in the context of the C OpenGL implementation.)

Comment: I can't cast `[]int` to `[]interface{}` so, eventually, my function to compute the size of a slice does not take a `[]interface{}` but just `interface{}`

Answer (score 3):

you can use (size) of the encoding/binary package.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := [...]int8{2, 3, 5, 7, 11} // Array
    s := []int64{2, 3, 5, 7, 11}   // Slice
    z := []int32{}                 // Even empty things

    fmt.Println(binary.Size(a)) // 5
    fmt.Println(binary.Size(s)) // 40
    fmt.Println(binary.Size(z)) // 0
}
```